# Setar o valor de um get(); num map

Tags: java

Como faço para dar um put no valor do ipOrigem sendo ele uma string? E também, sem refatorar o método que tem objetos usados em vários outros.

```
List<FileVO> arquivos = digitalizacaoVO.getArquivos();
Map<Long, List<FileVO>> arquivosMap = digitalizacaoVO.getArquivosMap();
String ipOrigem = digitalizacaoVO.getIpOrigem(); 


    if(arquivos != null && !arquivos.isEmpty()) {
        Long documentoId = documento != null ? documento.getId() : null;
        arquivosMap = new HashMap<>();
        arquivosMap.put(documentoId, arquivos);
    }
```

Comment: Qual o tipo da variável `digitalizacaoVO`?  Simplesmente `digitalizacaoVO.ipOrigem = novoIp` ou `digitalizacaoVO.setIpOrigem(novoIp)` não funciona?

Comment: funciona, mas o que preciso é que o valor desse getIpOrigem(), fique mapeado dentro do arquivosMap. Logo a baixo carrego os valores mapeados, jogo-os dentro de uma lista de array para depois salvar no metaDados da imagem que foi carregada. Não sei se ficou claro...

Comment: Você quer setar no HashMap o arquivo e o IP? Crie uma classe com essas duas propriedades e use ela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer esse valor dentro do seu map, sem modificar o map, você poderia simplesmente adicionar um campo à classe `FileVO`:

```
public class FileVO{
    private String ipOrigem;

//outros métodos bla blu

public void setIpOrigem(String ip){
this.ipOrigem = ip;
}

public String getIpOrigem(){
return this.ipOrigem;
}
}
```

Depois disso, bastaria usar um loop e preencher cada objeto da lista. Usando Java >8:

```
List<FileVO> arquivos = digitalizacaoVO.getArquivos();
String ipOrigem = digitalizacaoVO.getIpOrigem(); 
arquivos.forEach(a -> a.setIpOrigem(ipOrigem));
```

Assim a sua HashMap já estaria com o valor.

Comment: Funcionou cara! Na realidade eu já tinhaa um VO com os valores, só não conseguia mapeá-los. Muito obrigado!